# Security providers in Android and reflecting changes

Tags: java, android, security

I read

/platform/libcore.git/+/android-5.0.0_r2/luni/src/main/java/java/security/Security.java

file and i found, that there are public functions to change (insert, remove) security providers. My questions are:

1. Has each applications own security providers list ? So changes in list of security providers for one app, can't reflect in another ?
2. What about changes in "security.properties" file, has each app own version of this list ?

[Security.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore.git/+/android-5.0.0_r2/luni/src/main/java/java/security/Security.java)